# Standalone Programmer

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, flash

I am trying to make my small stand-allone programmer to work using this code: 
https://github.com/adafruit/Standalone-Arduino-AVR-ISP-programmer

But when I hookup everything and press button to flash my IC, I get this:

```
AdaBootLoader Bootstrap programmer (originally OptiLoader Bill Westfield (WestfW))

Type 'G' or hit BUTTON for next chip
Starting Program Mode [OK]

Reading signature:200
Searching for image...
 Not Found
Image fail
```

When I try to flash the same IC (just to make sure that IC is fine) via Arduino, there's no issues.

Any idea what can be wrong with this?

Comment: What IC are you programming?

Comment: I am trying to program ATMega328P-PU and with other assembled programmer which already have firmware which contains some variation of this OptiBoot_atmega328.hex it works.

Comment: Is images.cpp missing?

Comment: Nope, images.cpp is there, and signature there is fine

Comment: Looks like the problem was with fuses, fuses are not being set properly with this sketch. Once I write this IC with some other tool (like original OptiLoader) this sketch started to work.